# Powershell csv combine two columns and delete data after space

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv that will need to be scripted to update monthly it currently looks like this

```
UserID    Name
120       john doe
121       jane doe
122       mike name
123       joe blow
```

I need to keep the existing UserID and add the UserID data before the Name and delete the last name.

```
UserID    ID
120       120-john
121       121-jane
122       122-mike
123       123-joe
```

I have figured out renaming removing columns but I have no idea how to combine data from one to the other and remove the last name....

any help would be amazing! even if you can just fill in part of the issue I can keep playing

Comment: are you're saying the first example (w/ UserID,Name) is your input file? .. and the second example (w/ UserID,ID) is what you want the output to look like?

Comment: yes that's it exactly sorry if i wasn't clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily by importing the csv and passing it to Select-Object with a calculated property...

```
Import-Csv .\Input.csv | Select-Object UserID, @{n="ID";e={$_.UserID + "-" + $_.Name.Split(" ")[0]}}
```

And Pipe to Export-Csv if you want to save the output...

```
Import-Csv .\Import.csv | Select-Object UserID, @{n="ID";e={$_.UserID + "-" + $_.Name.Split(" ")[0]}} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation Output.csv
```

So what's going on here?  In the second part of my select statement, (the @{..} part) :

```
@{n="ID";e={$_.UserID + "-" + $_.Name.Split(" ")[0]}}
```

.. I'm saying, the name (n=) of the column is "ID", and the value is determined by the expression (e=), which is between the next pair of braces.
And that expression is saying, take the UserID ($*.UserID), plus a hyphen and append the first part of my $*.Name column (split by spaces).

Hope that helps (and made sense),
Cheers :)